# setting state in reactjs after filtering the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this data which is coming as props .All items in this array has a date attached to it .I have a a date coming from a function and I want my current state to hold all data for the date I sent in the function .

I used filter in order to achieve this but it doesn't seem to be working .
Here is the code for the same.

```
   updateWeather=(date)=>{
    console.log('date is',date);
     this.props.data.map((item)=>{
        console.log('item',item);
     })
    this.setState({

         today: this.props.data.filter( item =>item.date === date({
             date: item.date,
             time:item.time,
             temp: item.temp,
             humidity: item.humidity,
             weather: item.weather[0],
         }))
     });
 }`
```

Comment: Maybe try filtering the data and then set the state

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work because you're comparing objects. Variables assigned objects hold references to values in memory. So even if the objects **look** the same, they aren't, unless they're told to point at the same reference like `objA = objB` which your example isn't doing.

You need to adjust your code to compare the individual properties of the objects.

You might want to grab the `Object.keys()` of each of the objects your comparing, then create a `for` loop that compares the values like:

```js
const itemKeys = Object.keys(item);
const dateKeys = Object.keys(date);

for(let i = 0, n < itemKeys.length; i < n; i++){
    return item[itemKeys[i]] === date[dateKeys[i]]
}
```

Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if your object is not too big, and they don’t contain nested objects, so you basically can convert them as string and then compare them, like so

```
const obj1 = {...};
const obj2 = {...};

JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
```

So basically you are converting both object to be as string, but is you know that your object could have a nested object, so you shouldn’t do this, instead iterate the tree object to check that both object has the same vale.